# Silent Installation of exe file by python script

Tags: python

I tried with this code but gives an error (**The requested operation requires elevation**)

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import subprocess
import os
from os import system

url = "https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.1.9.2/App.exe"
#(dummy filepath)
output_file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Silent Installation\\download.exe"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

# Silent Install
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Silent Installation\\download.exe /SILENT ")


subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Silent Installation\\download.exe', '-ARG'], shell=True)
```

Comment: If you meant to ask a question, you should edit your Question to include it.

Comment: That URL gets a 404.  Which file are you downloading?  The installer certainly does require elevation.  The "portable" versions should be installable without admin privilege.

Comment: i wanted to download notepad++

Comment: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.1.9.2/npp.8.1.9.2.Installer.exe